# How to reload csv marker using ominvore on mapbox

Tags: javascript, csv, leaflet, mapbox

I'm new to coding and I want ask if there is a way to reload mapbox markers from a csv file using [omnivore.csv](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore/blob/master/README.md)

I've taken this example from mapbox.js [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/markers-from-csv-custom-style/)

I have tried to wrap the omnivore.csv in a function and use setInterval but that will cause the markers to keep stacking on each other.

I wanted to refresh/reload the markers every 4 min.
so far I have this:

```
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.2.1/mapbox.js'></script>
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-omnivore/v0.2.0/leaflet-omnivore.min.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.2.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />

<div id='map' style="height: 680px; width: 100%"></div>

<script>

L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiamhlcmVpcmEiLCJhIjoiY2p2aGxrajBqMDR5cDQzbzBrdTNqdmRteCJ9.tPKc_EYywojs5R-KEcKLGg'
map = L.mapbox.map('map')
map.setView([12.51602, -69.9719], 12);
L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11').addTo(map);

var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map);
omnivore.csv('nodes.csv', null, geojsonLayer)

 .on('ready', function () {

       this.eachLayer   ( function  (marker) {

             if (marker.toGeoJSON().properties.status === 'Online') {

                  marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                      'marker-color': '#29A912',
                      'marker-size': 'small'
                  }));
              }

              else if (marker.toGeoJSON().properties.status === 'Offline') {

                  marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                      'marker-color': '#be2626',
                      'marker-size': 'small'
                  }));
              }

              else if (marker.toGeoJSON().properties.status === 'Warning') {

                  marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                      'marker-color': '#E7BA14',
                      'marker-size': 'small'
                  }));
              }

              else if (marker.toGeoJSON().properties.status === 'Ranged') {

                  marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                      'marker-color': '#1487E7',
                      'marker-size': 'small'
                  }));
              }

              else if (marker.toGeoJSON().properties.status === 'Bandwidth') {

                  marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                      'marker-color': '#8114E7',
                      'marker-size': 'small'
                  }));
              }

              else {
                  marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({}));
              }

              marker.bindPopup(marker.toGeoJSON().properties.title + ', ' +
                  marker.toGeoJSON().properties.status);
      })
  })

</script>
```

my csv file looks like this :

"latitude","longitude","title","status"
"12.5218966025141","-70.0345627016134","MN BLUE CONDO","Online"
"12.5478471267241","-70.057234261884","MN OCEANIA","Online"
"12.47255415072","-69.960976765474","MN SB FCCA","Online"
"12.5347423282743","-70.0194866667518","MN SP FCCA","Online"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the geojsonlayer before you reload the markers.

```
var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map);
loadCSV();
setTimeout(function(){
     loadCSV();
  })
}, 4*60*100); //4min

function loadCSV(){
geojsonLayer.clearLayers()
omnivore.csv('nodes.csv', null, geojsonLayer)

 .on('ready', function () {

       this.eachLayer   ( function  (marker) {

             if (marker.toGeoJSON().properties.status === 'Online') {

                  marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                      'marker-color': '#29A912',
                      'marker-size': 'small'
                  }));
              }

              else if (marker.toGeoJSON().properties.status === 'Offline') {

                  marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                      'marker-color': '#be2626',
                      'marker-size': 'small'
                  }));
              }

              else if (marker.toGeoJSON().properties.status === 'Warning') {

                  marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                      'marker-color': '#E7BA14',
                      'marker-size': 'small'
                  }));
              }

              else if (marker.toGeoJSON().properties.status === 'Ranged') {

                  marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                      'marker-color': '#1487E7',
                      'marker-size': 'small'
                  }));
              }

              else if (marker.toGeoJSON().properties.status === 'Bandwidth') {

                  marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
                      'marker-color': '#8114E7',
                      'marker-size': 'small'
                  }));
              }

              else {
                  marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({}));
              }

              marker.bindPopup(marker.toGeoJSON().properties.title + ', ' +
                  marker.toGeoJSON().properties.status);
      })
}
```

Comment: the markers will show after 4min tho, is there a way to let them show immediately and then keep reloading after 4min?

Comment: I updated the code. Pls check the answer if it is working

Comment: yes, thanks a lot, I managed to get it working with your code